# how to filter the elements with muuri-react library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I'm working with react and I'm using a library called muuri-react. In this case I'm using it  to filter elements by a property named category (see the link of the code). this category receive a value. In this case I'm filter the elements by technologies for example one category named "javascript" other react, other node etc etc.
I'm following the oficial documentation but is no working.

```js
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { MuuriComponent } from "muuri-react";
import Item from "./components/Item";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");

  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([
    {
      key: 1,
      category: "javascript",
      ProjectName: "contador"
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      category: "javascript",
      ProjectName: "contador"
    },
    {
      key: 3,
      category: "javascript",
      ProjectName: "contador"
    },
    {
      key: 4,
      category: "react",
      ProjectName: "contador"
    },
    {
      key: 5,
      category: "react",
      ProjectName: "contador"
    },
    {
      key: 6,
      category: "react",
      ProjectName: "contador"
    },
    {
      key: 7,
      category: "react",
      ProjectName: "contador"
    },
    {
      key: 8,
      category: "react",
      ProjectName: "contador"
    },
    {
      key: 9,
      category: "node",
      ProjectName: "contador"
    },
    {
      key: 10,
      category: "node",
      ProjectName: "contador"
    },
    {
      key: 11,
      category: "javascript",
      ProjectName: "contador"
    }
  ]);

  const children = projects.map((project) => (
    <Item
      key={project.key}
      category={project.category}
      name={project.ProjectName}
    />
  ));

  let getActiveCategory = (id) => {
    let li = document.querySelectorAll(".li-portfolio");
    let arrayLi = Array.from(li);
    arrayLi.filter((option, i) => i === id && setData(option.innerHTML));
  };

  const filter = useCallback(
    ({ category }) => {
      //return category.indexOf(input) > -1;
      return category.indexOf(data) > -1;
    },
    [data]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li className={`li-portfolio`} onClick={() => getActiveCategory(0)}>
            All
          </li>
          <li
            className={`cursor-pointer inline-block mr-2 rounded-full py-2 px-8 li-portfolio`}
            onClick={() => getActiveCategory(1)}
          >
            javascript
          </li>
          <li
            className={`cursor-pointer inline-block mr-2 rounded-full py-2 px-8 li-portfolio`}
            onClick={() => getActiveCategory(2)}
          >
            react
          </li>
          <li
            className={`cursor-pointer inline-block rounded-full py-2 px-8 li-portfolio`}
            onClick={() => getActiveCategory(3)}
          >
            node
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <MuuriComponent
        propsToData={({ category }) => ({ category })}
        filter={filter}
      >
        {children}
      </MuuriComponent>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The idea is that when I clicked one of the elements in the  this filter the boxes by the name of the catgory. I have the value in the state but maybe I'm missing something that I can't see it. You can see the exercice in this link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/muuri-btpf1?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* React */
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { MuuriComponent } from "muuri-react";

// App.
const App = () => {
  // Items state.`enter code here`
  const [projects] = useState([
    {
      key: 1,
      category: "javascript",
      ProjectName: "contador"
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      category: "javascript",
      ProjectName: "contador"
    },
    {
      key: 3,
      category: "javascript",
      ProjectName: "contador"
    },
    {
      key: 4,
      category: "react",
      ProjectName: "contador"
    },
    {
      key: 5,
      category: "react",
      ProjectName: "contador"
    },
    {
      key: 6,
      category: "react",
      ProjectName: "contador"
    },
    {
      key: 7,
      category: "react",
      ProjectName: "contador"
    },
    {
      key: 8,
      category: "react",
      ProjectName: "contador"
    },
    {
      key: 9,
      category: "node",
      ProjectName: "contador"
    },
    {
      key: 10,
      category: "node",
      ProjectName: "contador"
    },
    {
      key: 11,
      category: "javascript",
      ProjectName: "contador"
    }
  ]);

  // Filter state.
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState({
    value: "all"
  });

  // Filter method.
  const filterFunction = useCallback(
    function (data) {
      var isFilterMatch =
        filter.value === "all" ? true : data.category === filter.value;
      return isFilterMatch;
    },
    [filter.value]
  );

  // Children.
  const children = projects.map(({ key, category }) => (
    <Item key={key} category={category} />
  ));

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Header */}

      <Select
        values={["All", "javascript", "react", "node"]}
        onChange={(e) => setFilter({ ...filter, value: e.target.value })}
      />

      <MuuriComponent
        propsToData={({ category }) => ({ category })}
        filter={filterFunction}
      >
        {children}
      </MuuriComponent>
    </div>
  );
};

// Item component.
const Item = ({ category }) => {
  return (
    <div className="muuri-item">
      <div className="item-content">
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-title">{category}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
const Select = ({ values, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <div className="control">
      <div className="control-icon">
        <i className="material-icons">&#xE152;</i>
      </div>
      <div className="select-arrow">
        <i className="material-icons">&#xE313;</i>
      </div>
      <select
        className="control-field filter-field form-control"
        onChange={onChange}
        defaultValue={values[0]}
      >
        {values.map((value, i) => (
          <option key={i} value={value.toLowerCase()}>
            {value}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: I used this as a resource: https://codesandbox.io/s/muuri-react-grid-1czo5 and my sandbox is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/muuri-forked-0vu71?file=/src/index.js